# How to use Pandas in Pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I tried to install Pandas in Project Interpreter under my Project -> Clicked on '+' .. but it says "Time out" and shows nothing. So I installed it using "py -m pip install pandas" in cmd, but I dont see it under Project Interpreter - there is only pip and setuptools.

What should I do to make it work ?

I am still getting an error:
    import pandas as pd
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that the pandas is not installed properly or not even installed at all.

The TimeOut error is generally for a connection problem, retry again after some time or try resetting your connection.